# Why is Mean Square error of a gamma variable not being calculated?

Tags: c, gamma-distribution, mean-square-error

So I have written this code that calculates mean square estimates of alpha and beta for different values of samples and betas. The value of alpha is 3, since we add three exponential distributions to create the gamma variable.

However, this code isn't giving me any correct output.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <stdlib.h> // Don't forget to include this

main()
{
  int n,N; // Sample size and number of simulations
  long double alpha=3,beta,suma=0.0,sumb=0.0,msea,mseb;  
  int i,j,k;
  printf("Enter the number of simulations");
  scanf("%d", &N);
  printf("Enter the sample size");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Enter the value of beta");
  scanf("%Lf", &beta);
  //Simulation starts to calculate MSE
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
      float msea=0.0,mseb=0.0,sum=0.0,sumsq=0.0; //Vlaue is reset at every iteration, so declared inside i loop
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)//each sample
        {
          float g;
          for(k=0;k<alpha;k++)
              g += (double)(-1/beta)*log(1-((double)rand()/RAND_MAX));//sum of exp is gamma
          sum += g;
          sumsq += g*g;
        }
      float xbar = sum/n;
      float var = sumsq/n - xbar*xbar;
      suma += pow ((xbar*xbar/var - alpha),2);
      sumb += pow ((xbar/var - beta),2);
    }
  msea = suma/n;
  mseb = sumb/n;
  printf("MSE of alpha is = %Lf", msea);
  printf("MSE of beta is = %Lf", mseb);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Can you help me find my error?

Comment: "isn't giving me any correct output." --> Post input used, output seen and output expected.

Comment: I used a sample input of 1000, 20 and 1.5. The outputs are nan or inf

Comment: Anweshan Goswami, best to append "sample input of 1000, 20 and 1.5. The outputs are nan or inf " and the expected output to the question.

Comment: Anweshan Goswami, Poor SO etiquette to change code once answers arrive as it invalidates them.  As needed _append_ new info.  Question rolled back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code has at least these problems:

**Uninitialized `g`**

```
 float g;
 for (k = 0; k < alpha; k++)
   g += (double) (-1 / beta) * log(1 - ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX));
```

**`log(0)`**

`log(1-((double)rand()/RAND_MAX))` might deliver `log(0)`.  I suspect `log(1 - (((double) rand() + 0.5)/ (RAND_MAX + 1u)))` will provide better distribution.

**3 FP types**

There is a lot of up converting, down converting going on with `float, double, long double`.

Use `double` throughout until it is determined other widths are needed.

**Unused objects**

`float msea=0.0,mseb=0.0` are not used.  Tip: Enable all warnings and save time.

**Use %g**

`"%g"` is more informative.

```
// printf("MSE of alpha is = %Lf", msea);
printf("MSE of alpha is = %Lg", msea);
```

---

OP reports "I made the changes, it's still giving nan output ".  I get

```
MSE of alpha is = 105.474
MSE of beta is = 31.4536
```

I suspect OP has not made all the changes.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <stdlib.h> // Don't forget to include this

int main() {
  int n, NN; // Sample size and number of simulations
  double alpha = 3, beta, suma = 0.0, sumb = 0.0, msea, mseb;
  int i, j, k;
  printf("Enter the number of simulations");
//  scanf("%d", &NN);
  printf("Enter the sample size");
//  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Enter the value of beta");
//  scanf("%f", &beta);
  NN = 1000;
  n = 20;
  beta = 1.5;
  //Simulation starts to calculate MSE
  for (i = 0; i < NN; i++) {
    double sum = 0.0, sumsq = 0.0; //Vlaue is reset at every iteration, so declared inside i loop
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) //each sample
        {
      double g = 0;
      for (k = 0; k < alpha; k++)
        g += (double) (-1 / beta)
            * log(1 - (((double) rand() + 0.5) / (RAND_MAX + 1u)));
      sum += g;
      sumsq += g * g;
    }
    double xbar = sum / n;
    double var = sumsq / n - xbar * xbar;
    suma += pow((xbar * xbar / var - alpha), 2);
    sumb += pow((xbar / var - beta), 2);
  }
  msea = suma / n;
  mseb = sumb / n;
  printf("MSE of alpha is = %g\n", msea);
  printf("MSE of beta is = %g\n", mseb);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I made the changes, it's still giving nan output

Comment: Is `%Lg` even legal?

Comment: @marco-a What reference are you using for `printf()`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm not using any reference, I googled it and stumbled upon a question here what `%lg` (note the lowercase `l`) means. One of the answers says you shouldn't use `%lg` and instead use`%g`.

Comment: @marco-a `"%lg"` is not `"%Lg"` and so does not apply.  Review [man prinf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) with its "L   A following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion  corresponds to a long double argument.".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That's why I asked

Comment: For some reason, my code was gibing output nan as long as I wasn't using long double. Upon using it, I'm getting correct answers